# In honor of last 2 Olympics: Taking first and second places

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Took a first place in [Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Winter_Olympics). But only took a second place in [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Summer_Olympics).

Identify the subject being discussed.

Comment: +1 From me. Why all the downvotes? It's easy, sure. But well done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alphabet soup?

> It looks like the letter r to me.